# ABC Conjecture: Simple example showing $\epsilon$ is necessary

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I was looking over Lang's discussion of the abc conjecture in his famous *Algebra* tome. He says

> We have to give examples such that for all $C>0$ there exist natural numbers $a$,$b$, $c$ relatively prime such that $a+b=c$ and $|a|>C N_0(abc)$. But trivially, $2^n | (3^{2^n} -1)$. We consider the relations $a_n+b_n=c_n$ given by $3^{2^n}-1 = c_n$. It is clear that these relations provide the desired examples.

Well, it is not clear to me. Can someone more algebraic than I please fill me in on what he's talking about?

I understand that because $2^n|(3^{2^n}-1)$, $N_0(3^{2^n}-1) \ll 3^{2^n}-1$, but I don't see which values of $a_n$ and $b_n$ will allow us to conclude anything like $|a|>C N_0(abc)$.

Comment: Maybe he meant for $a=3^{2^n}-1$, $b=1$, and $c=3^{2^n}$? In this case, $\frac{a}{N_0(abc)}$ can be bounded below by roughly $\frac{1}{3} 2^n$. That makes sense to me. What Lang wrote doesn't make sense to me (not the first time). Does this sound right to anyone?

Comment: Yes, this sounds right. More generally on can take $(a,b,c)=(1,3^{2m}-1,3^{2m})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\epsilon$ is necessary in the following sense. The abc-conjecture in the first version of Oesterle says: For every $\epsilon >0$ there are only **finitely many** abc-triples with quality $P(a,b,c)>1+\epsilon$, where $P(a,b,c)=\log c/(\log rad (abc))$, and $a,b,c$ coprime integers with $a+b=c$.
This is **wrong** for $\epsilon=0$, because of the above exmaples. To simplify it,
let 
$$
(a,b,c)=(1,9^n-1,9^n)
$$
for $n\ge 1$. Then $rad(abc)=3rad(b)$, and because of $8\mid (8+1)^n-1$ we have $8\mid b$ and $4\mid b/rad(b)$, so that $rad(b)\le b/4$, and $rad(abc)=3rad(b)\le 3b/4<c$, and hence
$$
P(1,9^n-1,9^n)>1+\frac{\log(4/3)}{2n\log 3}>1+\frac{1}{8n}>1,
$$
for **infinitely many** abc-triples.

Comment: Alright then, this matches my speculation above that there is a typo in Lang: he wrote $c_n=3^{2^n}-1$ when he should have written $c_n=3^{2^n}$. He used $3^{2^n}$, not $3^n$, because he was discussing the form of the abc conjecture in which $c < K(\epsilon) \mathrm{rad}(abc)^{1+\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

Aside: Thanks for asking this question, I was looking for Lang's examples and my copy of Algebra is at home.

Let me give what I feel is the simplest set of examples. These are essentially due to Erdos; see Problem 60 of [this book](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1963-14.pdf).

Let $(a_k, b_k, c_k) = \bigl(2^k(2^k -2), 1, (2^k -1)^2\bigr)$ for $k \geq 2$. Then we have $a_k + b_k  = c_k$, $\gcd(a_k,b_k,c_k) = 1$, and 
$$N_0(a_k b_k c_k) \mid (2^k - 1)(2^k - 2)< (2^k - 1)^2 = c_k.$$

In particular, $N_0(a_k b_k c_k) < c_k$ for all $k \geq 2$. This suffices to show that the $\epsilon$ in the ABC conjecture is necessary. Lang's examples are better; they tell us that $\limsup \frac{c}{N_0(abc)} = \infty$.